# Maximum likelihood estimator for multivariate normal distribution

Tags: maximum-likelihood, multivariate-normal-distribution

Let $\mathbf{X}$ be a N x p matrix where the rows are assumed to be independet with distribution $\mathcal{N}(z_i\mathbf{v},\Sigma)$. A fixed vector $\mathbf{z}\in\mathbb{R}^N$. I would like to show that the MLE of $\mathbf{v} = (v_1,..v_p)^T$ is

$$\hat{\mathbf{v}}^T=\frac{\mathbf{z}^T\mathbf{X}}{||\mathbf{z}||_2^2}$$

I've tried to work on the loglikelihood function
$$L(.)=\sum_{i=1}^N\log\left(\frac{\exp\left(-\frac{1}{2}(x-z_i\mathbf{v})^T\Sigma^{-1}(x-z_i\mathbf{v})\right)}{\sqrt{(2\pi)^p|\Sigma| }}\right)$$
to no avail.

Edit: My attempt. $x_i$ is the ith row in $\mathbf{X}$. Eventhough I used T for transpose, we assume p = 1 for now
$$L(.)\propto -\frac{1}{2}\sum_{i=1}^N (x_i-z_i\mathbf{v})^T\Sigma^{-1}(x_i-z_i\mathbf{v})$$
$$=-\frac{1}{2}\sum_{i=1}^N x_i^T\Sigma^{-1}x_i - 2(z_i\mathbf{v})^T\Sigma^{-1}x_i + (z_i\mathbf{v})^T\Sigma^{-1}z_i\mathbf{v}$$

Then the derivative and first order condition is
$$ -\frac{1}{2}\sum_{i=1}^N - 2x_i\Sigma^{-1}z_i+ 2 z_i^2\mathbf{v}^T\Sigma^{-1}= \sum_{i=1}^N x_i\Sigma^{-1}z_i-  z_i^2\mathbf{v}^T\Sigma^{-1}=0$$
Multiply the concentration matrix for both sides:
$$\Rightarrow\sum_{i=1}^N x_i z_i-  z_i^2\mathbf{v}^T=0$$
$$\Rightarrow \mathbf{v}^T=\frac{\sum_{i=1}^N x_i z_i}{\sum_{i=1}^N z_i^2}=\frac{\mathbf{z}^T\mathbf{X}}{||\mathbf{z}||_2^2}$$

Comment: Work out the case $p=1$ and let us know whether you succeed.  Then emulate your analysis for larger $p$.

Comment: Could explain why do you sum over i in you attempt ?

Comment: @Xi'an I don't it's exactly that. Mine is more on the technical side.

Comment: @MrSmithGoesToWashington I multiply the multivariate distributions(sum after log transform) to get the likelihood for MLE.

Comment: @whuber Think I may have worked out for p=1. I'm not sure how to scale up though. In particular how the differentiation works in this situation.

Comment: I think this question is not an exact duplicate ..I wonder why they marked it as a duplicate ...

Comment: agreed its not the same question at all